# MySQL query to find duplicate having more than (n) entries

Tags: mysql

I am having troubles with creating up this sql query to find records having more than (n) entries [n=1] in example

I have table

```
|--id-|--user_id--|
|  1  |    1      |
|  2  |    1      |
|  3  |    1      |
|  4  |    2      |
|  5  |    2      |
|  6  |    3      |
```

want to retrieve duplicates in my table

```
|--id-|--user_id--|
|  2  |    1      |
|  3  |    1      |
|  5  |    2      |
```

any help is very much appreciated, thanks for reading though

UPDATE:

I am using Mysql v5.1

Comment: so you don't want to retrieve ID 1 or 4?

Comment: yes, i dont want to fetch any records which has unique user_id, like id=1,4,6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be my approach

```
SELECT ID, USER_ID
  FROM TABLE
 GROUP USER_ID
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
MINUS
SELECT MIN(ID) ID, USER_ID
  FROM TABLE
 GROUP BY USER_ID
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: oops, didn't see that you're using MySQL. you might be able to tweak this query to get it working in MySQL

not sure which version of SQL your using but here's the sqlserver answer:

```
SELECT * from [table_name] GROUP BY user_id HAVING COUNT(*) > n
```

Comment: Spot on for MySQL and just what I needed.